# Git Concepts - Distinction between Head and Latest Commit

Tags: azure-devops, versioning, changeset, azure-repos, gitversion

Having used various version control systems in the past including TFS, the whole concept of file revisions was always easy to interpret and grasp. If I ever wanted to reference the latest version of files for instance, I only needed to identify what was listed as the latest changeset (or whatever terminology was used by that particular vcs) and that was pretty much it. Very easy.

I am a relative newbie to Git and so with the transition of TFS to Azure DevOps, I really find it confusing trying to get a handle on the concept of file versioning in Git. I have a couple of questions which are perhaps best depicted by the below screenshot.

For example,

1. What is HEAD and what is the distinction between it and the latest commit?
2. Why is a HEAD id different from the last commit id, when a file comparison run against the two ids indicates they are identical? In my case anda from the image below, this would be `43593c12` and `f493628c` respectively?

[image]

.

Answer (score 0):

HEAD in Git is essentially a commit pointer of your local repository.

The most important thing to note here is that HEAD is subjective (locally scoped) and would normally differ for every clone of repository.

The concept of latest commit in Git is ambiguous, since Git is a distributed system - hence "latest" is not clearly defined.

Generally, if you're new to Git, I recommend spending 1-2 weeks of time and reading Git Book thoroughly - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Specifically for your current question take a look at [The Three States](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F#_the_three_states) and [Branching basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).

Comment: Much appreciated @taleodor. Great feedback. Will certainly do some reading up on that recommended material.